# Difference between skin and CSS in Flex

Tags: css, apache-flex, skin

I am new in Flex. Was just wondering what is the difference between skin and CSS??
Why it is better to use skin over CSS in Flex. Could anybody please clear my doubt.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

CSS usually sets the styles (colors, etc) on the out-of-the-box skin.  Skins allow you to completely replace the visual appearance of a component with anything you want (images, vectors, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [great example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/09/08/extending-the-linkbutton-control-in-flex/) on creating custom skins.  In my experience, I had to create an Up-state background color on a LinkButton, which when using the default skin cannot be set.  By creating a custom skin, I was able to create functionality to respond to the color values I wanted.
So in short you can do a lot more with skins.